# React Render Components with Loop, but when state update it re-renders everything

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, state

I am having a problem with the loop. below sample code, notice that I have an array of objects as a dummyData.

the Component0 loads Component1 and this component is in charge of the initial loop,  each data from the dummyData represents  Component2 which has its own state.  On the last part "return" of Component1, I also manually call the Component2 3x with manual props.name.

When you run this code using this code sandbox, check the console for the logs. Noticed that when you click any STATIC it only renders the Component2 but when you click any DYNAMIC it will render the Component1 which is wrong because this will initiate the loop again.

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/embed/sharp-leftpad-4t9yi

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const dummyData = [
  { name: "DYNAMIC 1" },
  { name: "DYNAMIC 2" },
  { name: "DYNAMIC 3" },
  { name: "DYNAMIC 4" },
  { name: "DYNAMIC 5" }
];

const Component0 = () => {
  console.log("FIRST RENDER");
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Component1 dataList={dummyData} />
    </div>
  );
};

const Component1 = props => {
  console.log("SECOND RENDER");

  let listDom = null;
  let listDoms = [];

  props.dataList.map(data => {
    listDom = Component2(data);
    listDoms.push(listDom);
    return 1;
  });

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Component2 name="STATIC 1" />
      <Component2 name="STATIC 2" />
      <Component2 name="STATIC 3" />
      {listDoms}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

const Component2 = props => {
  let showed = true;
  const [listState, setListState] = useState(showed);

  const handleClick = props => {
    showed = listState ? false : true;
    setListState(showed);
  };

  if (listState) {
    console.log("RENDER : " + props.name);
    return (
      <div key={props.name}>
        <a href="#!" onClick={() => handleClick()}>
          <h1>{props.name}</h1>
        </a>
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return null;
  }
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Component0 />, rootElement);
```

Comment: The both answers are actually right. JSX compiles to the plain js function calls. Eg: `<Component2 name={data.name} />` becomes `createElement(Component2, {name: data.name})`. When you are passing a plain function `Component2(data)` it isn't wrapped by `createElement`. I suppose this is a crucial thing here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should update this:

```
let listDoms = [];

  props.dataList.map(data => {
    listDom = Component2(data);
    listDoms.push(listDom);
    return 1;
  });
```

to this:

```
let listDoms = props.dataList.map(data => {
    listDom = <Component2 key={data.name} name={data.name} />;
    return listDom;
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this

```
listDom = Component2(data);
listDoms.push(listDom);
```

With

```
listDoms.push(<Component2 name={data.name}/>)
```

The way you were initializing the component in React was wrong. Also try using ForEach instead of Map method. :)

Comment: @Valibhav why ForEach? I only use it if I need to break the loop, map is more faster ?

Comment: @SamTaps Map is used to change a list's values and returns a new list, foreach is used when you want to change the values of the same list and NOT create a new list.

Comment: To understand the difference check my answer and @Stavros's answer, he is creating a list while i am inserting in an existing list.

Comment: @SamTaps No problem :)

Comment: Actually the faster is a simple for loop but for the size of your data it shouldn't make a difference. I stayed with map as I try not to change the original code too much to avoid confusing the person asking and I updated it to be used properly (as push and return 1 is not the proper way)

Comment: @StavrosAngelis I agree with you. Looking at the use of map i could figure out that he was not aware of the difference between map and foreach, that is why i only changed the Component initialisation and didn't touch the loops. :)